# replacing values from two columns in R

Tags: r, replace, multiple-columns

I have a data frame that is 24 columns and the second and third column look like

```
1  2230
1  2300
1  2330 
1  2400
2  30
2  100
```

This is just a part of the columns. Column two has 48 ones then 48 twos then 48 threes and so on all the way to 365.  column three is the half hour time and starts with 30 then 100 then 130 then 200 and so on all the way to 2400.  With the patterns of each column I end up with the above example, where the last one corresponds to 2400.  I need to go though each column and replace the 2400 with 0 and that last value associated with 2400 to value plus one so I end up with

```
1  2230
1  2300
1  2330 
2  0
2  30
2  100
```

I can easily replace values for a single column but I don't know how to do it for two columns where one column depends on another.  I tried to use a for loop and if statement but coulnd't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fairly simple - if your data.frame (`df`) has columns `day` and `time`:

```
df[df$time==2400,]$day <- df[df$time==2400,]$day + 1

df[df$time==2400,]$time <- 0
```

If you're willing to learn to use the `data.table` package, this is much easier:

```
df[time==2400, c("day", "time"):= list(day + 1, 0)]
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks for the help! I didn't know about the data.table package.  Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

A single line solution:

```
df[df[3] == 2400, 2:3] <- cbind(df[df[3] == 2400, 2] + 1, 0)
```

Here, we just identify the rows that have 2400 as the 3rd col value, then replace the 2nd and 3rd column with the 2nd column + 1, and zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but a very simple, vectorized approach is to use a detection array to look for your '2400' values in the third column.

```
detection_array <- data[,3]==2400
data[detection_array,2] <- data[detection_array,2] + 1
data[detection_array,3] <- 0
```

---

**Step 1**: Create an array of TRUE/FALSE values that identify values of '2400' in the third column.

```
detection_array <- data[,3]==2400
```

**Step 2**: Add '1' to associated values in the second column.

```
data[detection_array,2] <- data[detection_array,2] + 1
```

**Step 3**: Change identified values in the third column to '0'.

```
data[detection_array,3] <- 0
```